# Can I tell PhpStorm what the return type of a function is going to be?

Tags: phpstorm

[image]

So if I have a function and in the PHPDoc I specify it'll return a `SqsProcessResult` object, then I call a function to create a new one of those objects but that function's PHPDoc say return type of `Object` (as it's a generic factory function) PhpStorm throws up an orange warning.

Can I annotate or otherwise tell PhpStorm the return type will be `SqsProcessResult`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, you can .. but due to the nature of the issue it may not be cleanest/elegant solution (at least that's what others may say).

Few options:

---

**#1.** Just suppress this inspection for that line.

- Place caret in the highlighted area and press <kbd>Alt + Enter</kbd> (or get the same menu via "light bulb" icon)
- Find the most suitable entry .. and press <kbd>Arrow Right</kbd> key (or mouse click on the tiny triangle icon) to expand submenu
- Once there -- choose `Suppress for statement` option -- a new inline PHPDoc comment will be added just above tat line that instructs PhpStorm to ignore that specific Inspection in the next line.

Will be something like this:

```
/** @noinspection PhpIncompatibleReturnTypeInspection */
return \Yii::createObject(...);
```

- Pros: no warning from IDE side
- Cons: extra PHPDoc comment to satisfy IDE (which is needed considering the circumstances)

---

**#2.** Use some intermediate variable that you can type hint in place.

Add something like this instead of that existing single line:

```
/** @var SqsProcessResult $res */
$res = \Yii::createObject(...);
return $res;
```

- Pros: no suppression comment
- Cons: extra variable (and still extra PHPDoc comment) for basically no reason

This one mainly can be used in longer methods where such variable (generic `Object`) will be created in the beginning/middle of the function body and then used later.

---

**#3.** Play with .metadata functionality and provide resolution logic for actual `\Yii::createObject()` (so IDE chooses the right class based on input parameter).

https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Advanced+Metadata

This is how quite a few tools working: IDE helper for Laravel, Symfony helpers, DI Container helpers etc

Comment: Thanks! The first option is what I was looking for to avoid creating variables purely for code inspection. FYI the annotation is `/** @noinspection PhpIncompatibleReturnTypeInspection */`

Comment: Check updated answer -- option #3. If done properly -- no comments will be needed (but you better ask this on Yii dedicated forums etc -- they should have a solution already, I would assume). Not this one ... but among these lines: http://yiifeed.com/news?id=72